# magento saveAction - for beginners

Tags: php, magento

I am a Magento beginner so please bear with me...
I am creating a simple extension for my site to add a custom field to my Tags in adminhtml. The custom field is just a number which I need to identify a specific Z-block (cms block extension) so that I can access it as a widget and show it on the frontend in the Tag "category".

I have created a custom module which is working: I set a field in the form using $fieldset and have extended TagController.php, both of which are being used (I made a simple trial to see whether or not they had been recognized). However, I do not know how to go about saving my custom field to DB (whether amending saveAction is enough, and I haven't done it properly, or if I need to add a custom Model or sql install).

Sorry for the "basic" question but I'm new at this, and have mostly done frontend dev (so my extension knowledge is simply limited).

Thank you to anyone who can help...
Claudia

NEW TAG FORM:

```
public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    $this->setId('tag_form');
    $this->setTitle(Mage::helper('tag')->__('Block Information'));
}

/**
 * Prepare form
 *
 * @return Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Form
 */
protected function _prepareForm()
{
    $model = Mage::registry('tag_tag');

    $form = new Varien_Data_Form(
        array('id' => 'edit_form', 'action' => $this->getData('action'), 'method' => 'post')
    );

    $fieldset = $form->addFieldset('base_fieldset',
        array('legend'=>Mage::helper('tag')->__('General Information')));

    if ($model->getTagId()) {
        $fieldset->addField('tag_id', 'hidden', array(
            'name' => 'tag_id',
        ));
    }

    $fieldset->addField('form_key', 'hidden', array(
        'name'  => 'form_key',
        'value' => Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getFormKey(),
    ));

    $fieldset->addField('store_id', 'hidden', array(
        'name'  => 'store_id',
        'value' => (int)$this->getRequest()->getParam('store')
    ));

    $fieldset->addField('name', 'text', array(
        'name' => 'tag_name',
        'label' => Mage::helper('tag')->__('Tag Name'),
        'title' => Mage::helper('tag')->__('Tag Name'),
        'required' => true,
        'after_element_html' => ' ' . Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('[GLOBAL]'),
    ));

     $fieldset->addField('zblock', 'text', array(
        'name' => 'zblock_id',
        'label' => Mage::helper('tag')->__('Z-Block Id'),
        'title' => Mage::helper('tag')->__('Z-Block Id'),
        'required' => true,
        'after_element_html' => ' ' . Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('[GLOBAL]'),
    ));

    $fieldset->addField('status', 'select', array(
        'label' => Mage::helper('tag')->__('Status'),
        'title' => Mage::helper('tag')->__('Status'),
        'name' => 'tag_status',
        'required' => true,
        'options' => array(
            Mage_Tag_Model_Tag::STATUS_DISABLED => Mage::helper('tag')->__('Disabled'),
            Mage_Tag_Model_Tag::STATUS_PENDING  => Mage::helper('tag')->__('Pending'),
            Mage_Tag_Model_Tag::STATUS_APPROVED => Mage::helper('tag')->__('Approved'),
        ),
        'after_element_html' => ' ' . Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('[GLOBAL]'),
    ));

    $fieldset->addField('base_popularity', 'text', array(
        'name' => 'base_popularity',
        'label' => Mage::helper('tag')->__('Base Popularity'),
        'title' => Mage::helper('tag')->__('Base Popularity'),
        'after_element_html' => ' ' . Mage::helper('tag')->__('[STORE VIEW]'),
    ));

    if (!$model->getId() && !Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->getTagData() ) {
        $model->setStatus(Mage_Tag_Model_Tag::STATUS_APPROVED);
    }

    if ( Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->getTagData() ) {
        $form->addValues(Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->getTagData());
        Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->setTagData(null);
    } else {
        $form->addValues($model->getData());
    }

    $this->setForm($form);
    return parent::_prepareForm();
}
```

NEW CONTROLLER:

```
public function saveAction()
{
    if ($postData = $this->getRequest()->getPost()) {
        if (isset($postData['tag_id'])) {
            $data['tag_id'] = $postData['tag_id'];
        }

        $data['name']               = trim($postData['tag_name']);
        $data['zblock']             = $postData['zblock_id'];
        $data['status']             = $postData['tag_status'];
        $data['base_popularity']    = (isset($postData['base_popularity'])) ? $postData['base_popularity'] : 0;
        $data['store']              = $postData['store_id'];

        if (!$model = $this->_initTag()) {
            Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addError(Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('Wrong tag was specified.'));
            return $this->_redirect('*/*/index', array('store' => $data['store']));
        }

        $model->addData($data);

        if (isset($postData['tag_assigned_products'])) {
            $productIds = Mage::helper('adminhtml/js')->decodeGridSerializedInput(
                $postData['tag_assigned_products']
            );
            $model->setData('tag_assigned_products', $productIds);
        }

        try {
            $model->save();
            Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addSuccess(Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('The tag has been saved.'));
            Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->setTagData(false);

            if (($continue = $this->getRequest()->getParam('continue'))) {
                return $this->_redirect('*/tag/edit', array('tag_id' => $model->getId(), 'store' => $model->getStoreId(), 'ret' => $continue));
            } else {
                return $this->_redirect('*/tag/' . $this->getRequest()->getParam('ret', 'index'));
            }
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addError($e->getMessage());
            Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->setTagData($data);

            return $this->_redirect('*/*/edit', array('tag_id' => $model->getId(), 'store' => $model->getStoreId()));
        }
    }

    return $this->_redirect('*/tag/index', array('_current' => true));

}
```

The custom field I'm trying to add is "zblock"...thanks and, again, bear with me! :)

Comment: pls consider to add some code. it'll help a lot to understand and help you

Comment: Right, my mistake :) I'll edit my post, thanks for the advice!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First add the field in database table. 
For example if you want to add in your custom table.

```
 ALTER TABLE myCustomModuleTable ADD COLUMN 'myCustomField' int(10);
```

Thenafter, In your controller action take the model object of that table and set the field.

If you are adding data in existing table row:

```
 $value = 6;
    $rowInWhichIWantToSave = Mage:getModel('companyname/modulename')->load($rowId);
    $rowInWhichIWantToSave->setData('myCustomField',$value)->save();
```

If you are adding a new row:

```
$value = 6;
$rowInWhichIWantToSave = Mage:getModel('companyname/modulename');
$rowInWhichIWantToSave->setData('myCustomField',$value)->save();
```

Hope this helps!!